# How to handle collision openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

This is separate to a previous question I asked.
To make the collision detection simpler I am now using euclidean distance to work out if objects intersect.

- I am working in a 3D environment using openGL with bounding walls around the
  edges.
- I have a player (just displayed as a quad for now)
- There are also several randomly displayed cylinders acting as pillars, created using gluCylinder.

Intersection with the walls is fine, and I know that if there is an intersection with the left wall for example the player should be positioned at an X co ordinate that is 0.5 away from the bounding wall.That way if the player is going to go through the wall then it will have the appearance of being able to walk into the wall but not through it.

I am having trouble with the inner pillars, and what i should do with the player when i detect they are within a certain distance of a pillar.

I am using a euclidean distance calculation to detect collisions when diet is < than a value 1 for example.

```
double dist = sqrt(pow((playerX - xPosi[i]),2) + pow((playerZ - zPosi[i]),2));
```

xPosi[i] and zPosi[i] are arrays holding the x and z co ordinates of my pillars, and player X and Z hold the co ordinates of the player. Could anyone suggest how to handle the interaction with the pillars, as i now have the collision detection working.

The player will only be travelling in either a +ve or -ve x direction or +ve or -ve z direction, I would like the player to stop if a collision is detected and no longer be able to move through the pillar.

Comment: If you're doing collision detection, you probably want to use [Bullet](http://www.bulletphysics.org/wordpress) instead of writing your own collision objects and low-level libraries. There's other solutions, and in your case you might even be able to get away with a 2D collision library if your objects don't interact on one of the axes.

Comment: I don't really want to use a collision library for what I thought could be a relatively simple task. The complexity of what I am doing I don't think would require any extern libraries

Comment: Naive collision detection is easy, but it doesn't always work very well. If you want to do it properly, you'll need a good reference like [Real-Time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net). It's not just a case of testing if two objects overlap, but if they *did* overlap during their motion. Objects moving quickly will jump through walls otherwise. If you use a library, you'll get a lot of things for free, like physics.

Comment: Upvote to @tadman for the complexity point, although I will wholeheartedly emphasize that there is great value to learning physics and subsystems in general and not having a library do it for you. As always, though, you must pick your battles - if physics is low priority and not something you want to spend a lot of time on, then using a library is the way to go.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher You should *absolutely* read a good reference on how this stuff works and experiment with implementing it yourself, but it takes a very, very long time to get this working flawlessly enough to call it done. That book I linked to goes into extreme detail on different algorithms, data structures, and the math behind their techniques. It's extremely comprehensive and a must-read for anyone trying to understand the fundamentals. Bullet Physics not only has all that implemented, it has it *optimized* to work efficiently.